# Jasper Report table overflow

Tags: jasper-reports

I'am using Jasper report. Datas which I send to page doesn't fill into the jrTable like following image. How I can make it stretch ? Thanks in advance.

```
    <componentElement>
            <reportElement key="table 5" style="table 5" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" x="3" y="323" width="546" height="302" isPrintWhenDetailOverflows="true"/>
            <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <datasetRun subDataset="bufferList">
                    <datasetParameter name="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE">
                        <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{bufferList}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                    </datasetParameter>
                </datasetRun>
                <jr:column width="90">
                    <jr:tableHeader style="table 5_TH" height="30"/>
                    <jr:columnHeader style="table 5_CH" height="30">
                        <staticText>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30"/>
                            <text><![CDATA[buffer_name]]></text>
                        </staticText>
                    </jr:columnHeader>
                     ..........
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is unclear what is this a crosstable?, a jr table?, show some jrxml create a [mcve]

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer .It is jrTable

Comment: and it's exiting the page?, this seems like a a design issue?, make the table smaller then the page?, use stretchWIthOverflow on textFields?

Comment: No , on design side I already have made it smaller but it getting bigger when it run and show page :/

Comment: hmm are you sure your re-compiling the jrxml after that you have changed it? this is the width="546" check widths of columns and page. Jasper respects your width as in design so I think you are having another problem

Comment: yeah surely , I look over one more time. But everything looks is ok :/ Maybe I must change any poperties filed of Table.I cange printwhenoverflow to true.But still it doesnt work

Comment: I just reduce column width and increase height of columns.But it is not a good way :/